# Continuous integration - exec rsync with ssh fails silently

Tags: php, linux, ssh, jenkins, rsync

I've wracked my brains on this one for days and I've gotten nowhere.

I have a Jenkins continuous integration server that is building to a separate nginx webserver, both on AWS.

### The problem

My rsync command, when run by the build server user through a PHP `passthru()`, is failing silently.

To move files between servers after a build, I am using a PHP script that uses `rsync` with `ssh` to connect to update the webserver. The snippet is below.

**PHP:**

```
$rsync = "rsync -avzlO --no-g -e 'ssh -i ".$identity." -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \
-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' ".$workspace." root@".$host.":/var/www/public_html/";
echo($rsync);
echo(passthru($rsync));
```

Executing this command through the command line, either by a `php name-of-file.php` call or by simply running the echoed command succeeds in performing the rsync. However, when the command is called as a post-build step through the Jenkins server, the command fails silently.

To note: The user that I have access to is the `ec2-user` user. The user that Jenkins runs under is the `jenkins` user. I have confirmed this by running an `echo(exec('whoami'));` immediately before the `rsync`.

### What I've tried

It feels like a permission or owner error. I have messed with them until my eyes are about ready to bleed.

Currently, they stand as follows:

```
-rw------- 1 jenkins  ec2-user 1679 Feb 12 01:37 jenkins.pem
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jenkins  ec2-user 4097 Feb 12 01:51 push_to_cluster_l4.php
```

I have tried creating a new ssh key pair, and verifying that it allows passwordless login to the webserver.

I have tried changing `passthru()` to `exec()` and `system()`

I've added logging of the `passthru()` call through an echo, piping to a file, assigning to a variable and outputting, to no avail - it fails silently each time.

I know that what I'm trying to achieve is possible, because not only does it work when performed through the shell, but the same code powers deployment to our other clusters. There is just some hangup somewhere preventing the deployment from happening on the new webserver.

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: I noticed that the Jenkins user had no shell - so I changed it to `/bin/bash`, but that does not seem to have had any effect. I also tried executing the command as the Jenkins user using `sudo -u jenkins php push_to_cluster_l4.php`, which was successful. I used http://us1.php.net/posix_getpwuid to verify that it was indeed the Jenkins user executing the PHP. No dice.

Answer (score 3):

The issue was an incorrectly configured public SSH key on the client side. While it existed, it was not in the `.ssh` directory, and was not owned by the user Jenkins was using to connect for the `rsync`. Once I fixed that, I was able to connect without issue.

The takeaway? `rsync` fails silently when the SSH key file does not allow for passwordless login at the destination. Hopefully my time and frustration helps some poor soul in the future.

Comment: Found another ~silent rsync transfer fail. If rsync file to dir where user doesn't have permissions to write files then rsync transfers all files over network fully. Then reports fail to write. Painful when files are large and transfer is slow. Looks like it is working. No error until too late. 'rsync -avzhP <files> -e ssh user@host:/dir/where/user/cannot/write' 'rsync  version 3.0.7  protocol version 30'